# How do you centralize one config for multiple repositories across packages?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to set up multiple data source in my spring project.

The first thing I realize is that if you have multiple data sources, you can no longer auto config.

In that case most tutorials will tell you to create two config classes each inside the package of the corresponding repositories.

But what if I have repositories across many packages? And all of them uses the same config?

So let's say I have

```
com.company.domain1.repositories
com.company.domain2.repositories
...
com.company.domain8.repositories
...
com.company.domainN.repositories
```

So I want one config for all repositories, except for domain8 where I want a different config (that connects to a different data source).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

The point of having multiple configuration classes in different packages with the respective repositories is to make sure for each and every repository it is clear which configuration to use.

You can also achieve that by using the [`includeFilter`/`exludeFilter` attributes of `@EnableJpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html#excludeFilters--)